# Seeing GemWrappers error when doing bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, rake

Doing `bundle install` using `rails 6.1.5.11` and `ruby 2.7.6`, I keeping seeing a GemWrappers error after installing each gem e.g.

```
    Fetching sprockets 4.0.3
    Installing sprockets 4.0.3
    GemWrappers: Can not wrap not executable file: rake
    Fetching sprockets-rails 3.4.2
    Installing sprockets-rails 3.4.2
    GemWrappers: Can not wrap not executable file: rake
```

The bundle install works, but how do I eliminate this error/warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gem `gem-wrappers` is not actively maintained it seems. Last update was in 2017. As per Rubygems it relies on rake < 11.

https://rubygems.org/gems/gem-wrappers

Although Rails 6.1.5.1 installs rake 13.0.6

https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions/6.1.5.1

so if you have `gem-wrappers` as a dependency, try removing it.

If `gem-wrappers` is not in your Gemfile and you do not need it, try:

```
gem uninstall gem-wrappers
```